# Sending image in push notification to Android phones using phonegap plugin

Tags: angularjs, image, push-notification, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"data\": {\"message\":\"test image\",\"image\":\"http://www.cespage.com/design/graphics/redstar.gif\",\"title\":\" Shopping!!!\"} }"
}
```

This is the data that I post from AWS SNS console, and the app has  this plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

We use ionic framework and the config.xml has this

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.5.0" />
```

I explored 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushonnotification-callback and 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/src/android/com/adobe/phonegap/push/GCMIntentService.java

if the data contains an element called image, it should load the image from the image url. But it doesn't. How to troubleshoot this issue?

PS : I am a backend developer and do not have exposure to app development.

Comment: Hey , so have you solve your issue ?,i am looking for the same